# How can I attach event handlers to dynamically-generated DOM elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-handling

I have a `<ul>` tag that I want to append some `<li>` tags inside. Example:

```
$('body').append("<ul id='myUL'>").find("ul");
$('#myUL').append('<li id='a'>a</li>');
$('#myUL').append('<li id='b'>b</li>');
```

I want to give every `<li>` a different click event. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('<ul></ul>')
    .attr('id', 'myUL')
    .append(
        $('<li>a</li>').click(function() {
            alert('First one clicked');
        })
    )
    .append(
        $('<li>b</li>').click(function() {
            alert('Second one clicked');
        })
    )
    .appendTo('body')
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstLi = $('<li id='a'>a</li>');
firstLi.click(function() { ... });
$('body').append("<ul id='myUL'>").find("ul");
$('#myUL').append(firstLi);
$('#myUL').append('<li id='b'>b</li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put some marker on the list item and give them all the same event? Or, better yet, use a `live()` event and then you don't even need to add one:

```
$('#myUL').append('<li id='a'>a</li>');
```

with:

```
$(function() {
  $("#myUL li").live("click", function() {
    if (this.id == "a") {
      ...
    }
  });
});
```

Otherwise just reverse the order and the syntax is much nicer:

```
$"<li></li>").attr("id", "a").text("a").appendTo("#myUL").click(function() {
  ...
});
```

You could simply do this:

```
$"<li id='" + a + "'>" + a + "</li>")..appendTo("#myUL").click(function() {
  ...
});
```

but I don't recommend this when dealing with dynamic input because you may not properly escape special characters whereas calling `attr()` and `text()` will correctly escape content and make you less susceptible to XSS exploits.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('body').append("<ul id='myUL'>").find("ul");
$('#myUL').append('<li id='a' onclick="myeventHandler(event)" >a</li>');
$('#myUL').append('<li id='b' onclick="myeventHandler(event)" >b</li>');

function myeventHandler(ev){
        var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
          alert(target.id);
}
```